# Is it possible to have an image follow mouse cursor without blocking its click events?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image follow my mouse cursor (image is set to be directly beneath the cursor). All is well except now I cant really click on anything, because when i click, im just selecting the image and not the elements under it. Is there anyway to ignore the image when it comes to mouse events like click or mousedown?

I dont want to use a custom cursor (cursor: url(...)). Just need the mouse events to propagate to the elements under the image.

**Edit:**

adding pointer-events: none; sorta works, but disables cursor: none.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: @PeeHaa please read edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS for the image, you can make clicks pass through it by adding `pointer-events: none;`.

See [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: solves the problem, but creates another one. It ignores cursor: none for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fixed html div that follows the mousecursor using javascript. This way you are not limited to only images but also content.